# Automatically remove duplicate recipients before manually send ReplyAll, (Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set)

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am using a macro to add specific recipients (Contact_group) to my `ReplyAll` email, depends on a condition and it works as it should. 
But I found that the original mail may already contain some recipients from my “contact_group” and this leads to a duplication. 
I googled and found a code to remove duplicate recipients, and because this code (`Sub Remove_Duplicate_Recipients`) is lengthy then I put on a separate module. 
When I manually run `Sub Remove_Duplicate_Recipients` while the ReplyAll window is still open, then it works correctly as it should. 
For automation purpose, I need to run automatically the cited sub , by calling it from `ThisOutlookSession`, 
But I got

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

At this line `Set objCurrentMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItemof`  on `Sub Remove_Duplicate_Recipients`

The below code is found in (ThisOutlookSession)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Private WithEvents myAttExp As Explorer
Private WithEvents myAttOriginatorMail As MailItem
Dim WithEvents oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myAttExp = ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub myAttOriginatorMail_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  If Response.Body Like "*Test*" Then
      Response.Recipients.Add ("TestGroup")  'name of Contact_Group
       Response.Recipients.ResolveAll
       Remove_Duplicate_Recipients
  End If

End Sub

Private Sub myAttExp_SelectionChange()
  On Error Resume Next
    If TypeOf myAttExp.Selection.Item(1) Is MailItem Then
        Set myAttOriginatorMail = myAttExp.Selection.Item(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

And this sub is found on a separate module:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Remove_Duplicate_Recipients()

    Dim objCurrentMail As MailItem
    Dim objRecipients As Recipients
    Dim ContactGroupFound As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
 
    Set objCurrentMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    
    ContactGroupFound = True
 
    While ContactGroupFound = True
          Set objRecipients = objCurrentMail.Recipients
          ContactGroupFound = False
 
    'Expand the contact groups in "To" field
          For i = objRecipients.Count To 1 Step -1
              If objRecipients(i).AddressEntry.DisplayType <> olUser Then
                 For n = 1 To objRecipients(i).AddressEntry.Members.Count
                     If objRecipients(i).AddressEntry.Members.Item(n).DisplayType = olUser Then
                        objCurrentMail.Recipients.Add (objRecipients(i).AddressEntry.Members.Item(n).Address)
                     Else
                        objCurrentMail.Recipients.Add (objRecipients(i).AddressEntry.Members.Item(n).Name)
                        ContactGroupFound = True
                     End If
                 Next
                 objRecipients(i).Delete
              End If
          Next i
          objRecipients.ResolveAll
    Wend
 
'Remove the duplicate recipients
    For i = objRecipients.Count To 1 Step -1
        For n = (i - 1) To 1 Step -1
            If objRecipients(i).Address = objRecipients(n).Address Then
               objRecipients(i).Delete
               Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the ReplyAll item in `myAttOriginatorMail_ReplyAll`:

```vb
Private Sub myAttOriginatorMail_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  
    If Response.Body Like "*Test*" Then
        Response.Recipients.Add ("TestGroup")  'name of Contact_Group
        Response.Recipients.ResolveAll
       
        Remove_Duplicate_Recipients_withParameter Response

    End If

End Sub

Sub Remove_Duplicate_Recipients_withParameter(objCurrentMail As MailItem)

    'Dim objCurrentMail As MailItem
    Dim objRecipients As Recipients
    Dim ContactGroupFound As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
 
    'Set objCurrentMail = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    
    ContactGroupFound = True
 
    ' ...
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I test and it works , Please Could you point out the problems with my own code?

Comment: If you reply from the selection there is no `Inspector`. A `Response.Display` before calling your original code may be sufficient.